# Restore values in a time series table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to restore the most actual values from a time series table for the other values in specific time.

Let is say, that we have a table like that (I use SQL Server 2016), (this is pseudo-code, I did not check whether it works):

```
use sample
go

-- create time series table
drop table if exists dbo.PropertyHistory
go
create table dbo.PropertyHistory (
  Id int
, Timestamp datetime
, Value int
)
go

-- fill dbo.PropertyHistory
insert into
  dbo.PropertyHistory(Id, Timestamp, Value)
values
   (1, '2019-01-01 12:00:00', 10)
 , (1, '2019-01-01 13:00:00', 20)
 , (2, '2019-01-01 13:00:00', 15)
 , (3, '2019-01-01 14:00:00', 1)
 , (4, '2019-01-01 15:00:00', 10)
 , (1, '2019-01-01 16:00:00', 6)
 , (4, '2019-01-01 17:00:00', 5)
 , (2, '2019-01-01 17:00:00', 50)
 , (2, '2019-01-01 19:00:00', 7)
 , (1, '2019-01-01 19:00:00', 44)
go
```

I need to for example each row with the property id = 1 to have the last actual value (actual by datetime of course) of the property id = 2.

```
   |  Id |       Timestamp     | Value | Property2Value |
   -------------------------------------------------------
   |  1  | 2019-01-01 12:00:00 |   10  |     NULL       |
   |  1  | 2019-01-01 13:00:00 |   20  |     15         |
   |  1  | 2019-01-01 16:00:00 |   6   |     15         |
   |  1  | 2019-01-01 19:00:00 |   44  |     7          |
   -------------------------------------------------------
```

The ideas:

1. To create the function kinda of `create function A (@propertyId int, @toDateTime datetime)` which finds the latest row for the specified value restricted by the datetime. And then for each row with property id = 1 cross apply to this function. The performance is bad.
2. I think that it is possible to somehow use cumulative sum kinda of `sum (case when PropertyId = 2 then Value else 0 end) over (order by Timestamp)` but it will be cumulate more and more...

So, please help me to obtain the expected result.

Comment: why the value of `Property2Value` is `NULL` for `2019-01-01 13:00:00` ?

Comment: @Squirrel, oh my god, really, thank you very much, I will edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is a good use of `apply`:

```
select ph1.*, ph2.value as value2
from propertyhistory ph1 outer apply
     (select top (1) ph2.*
      from propertyhistory ph2
      where ph2.id = 2 and ph2.timestamp <= ph1.timestamp
      order by ph2.timestamp desc
     ) ph2
where ph1.id = 1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e83cf42d8161410b4e338d16eb9f6223) is a db<>fiddle.

You can also do this with window functions, with the following logic:

- For each row in the original data, get the most recent "2" timestamp.
- Get the value for the "2" timestamp.
- Filter down to just the "1"s

This looks like:

```
select ph.*
from (select ph.*,
             max(case when ph.id = 2 then ph.value end) over (partition by timestamp_2) as value_2
      from (select ph.*,
                   max(case when ph.id = 2 then ph.timestamp end) over (order by ph.timestamp) as timestamp_2
            from propertyhistory ph
           ) ph
     ) ph
where id = 1;
```

Comment: Hello @Gordon. The first one is ok, because it is logically correct what is necessary. But the second one no, as it is very particular solution.

But it is fine, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We can handle this requirement by a judicious use of `ROW_NUMBER`, combined with some pivoting logic:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Timestamp DESC) rn
    FROM dbo.PropertyHistory
)

SELECT
    1 AS Id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Id = 1 THEN Timestamp END) AS Timestamp,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Id = 1 THEN Value END) AS Value,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Id = 2 THEN Value END) AS Property2Value
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    rn
ORDER BY
    MAX(CASE WHEN Id = 1 THEN Timestamp END);
```

[image]

### Demo

The idea here is to compute a row number label for each record, numbered separately for each `Id` value.  Then, we can aggregate by the row number, which brings the `Id` values from 1 and 2 into line, in a single record.

Comment: Excuse me, but a little bit hard-coded logic.

Look, if you run the next statement for this database:
`
insert into
  dbo.PropertyHistory(Id, Timestamp, Value)
values
 (2, '2019-01-01 17:00:00', 50)
`
you will have the other result than expected in the question, but it should be the same.

I am sorry, if the sample was not clear.

Here is the demo: [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9ff1af10dcad3b0a1f8ec4990427a849)

Comment: This completely answers what you actually asked.  If you have other requirements, then edit your question.  And being rude will not get you very much help on this website.

Comment: I am sorry, if I was rude. Yes, sure. Thanks.